# Concurrent get timestamp plus sequence from Oracle

Tags: oracle

background: two application nodes, three Oracle node.

I have a sequence, ddl like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "XXX_SEQ"  MINVALUE 10 MAXVALUE 99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10 NOCACHE  ORDER  CYCLE ;
```

And I use this to generate the id as my primary key

```
SELECT 'FWK2-' || TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF2') || '-' || XXX_SEQ.nextval AS MSG_REQ_ID FROM DUAL;
```

But when concurrent generate the id, it hit the duplicate issue, in milliseconds it generate the duplicate id.

It is part of the log

```
2019-09-03 04:40:17,501 FWK2-2019090304401699-43 
2019-09-03 04:40:17,010 FWK2-2019090304401699-43
```

And I checked in the 99 milliseconds, there are no more than 99 msg that would make the sequence cycle to hit the duplicate issue.

I suspect it should be the ddl issue

Dose anyone know about how to optimize it?

---

actually, in my PROD env, i have 3 application that use this method to generate, and each application has 2 nodes. Suppose 3 application are A,B,C.
A and C has only one place to generate id
B has more than three place to generate id

and one more strange that as my sequence is order, why the id in db is not order?

```
FWK2-2019090304394159-34
FWK2-2019090304394280-37
FWK2-2019090304394298-35
FWK2-2019090304394311-36
FWK2-2019090304394354-40
FWK2-2019090304394359-38
```

---

Update

Although I test with sequence `NOCACHE`, `ORDER`, under Jmeter use 3 api, each api 300 threads.

The id would not be order, like this:

```
FWK2-2019090403025046-67
FWK2-2019090403025046-68
FWK2-2019090403025050-69
FWK2-2019090403025053-10
FWK2-2019090403025053-11
FWK2-2019090403025053-31
FWK2-2019090403025053-39
FWK2-2019090403025053-40
FWK2-2019090403025053-41
FWK2-2019090403025053-42
FWK2-2019090403025053-46
FWK2-2019090403025053-47
FWK2-2019090403025053-70
FWK2-2019090403025053-71
FWK2-2019090403025053-72
```

Comment: Try `SELECT /*+ NO_RESULT_CACHE */ 'FWK2-' ...` though caching should not have happened here. (The above is a _hint_ in an SQL statement.)

Comment: TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF2') rise time resolution? change FF2 to FF3 or FF4?

Comment: If this is a direct extract from your log I'd ask why it is that the log messages are out of sequence, with the message timestamped 04:40:17.501 preceding the one timestamped 04:40:17.010?

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say "three Oracle node", are you referring to a three node Oracle RAC cluster?  Or three separate databases?

Comment: You are suggesting that `XXX_SEQ.nextval` is returning the same value for two simultaneous queries and that it is NOT due to the `CYCLE` clause.  In other words, you are suggesting a major bug in the Oracle database.  Yes, bugs happen and yes a RAC sequence with `ORDER` is something of an edge case.  But I'll lay money (and maybe lose) that the problem is in your application code.  Can you post more of it?  How exactly does the key go from being generated to getting written to your log?

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry it is my fault. Actually there are 3 or 4 different place to call the function to generate the id, i capture the log with no-ordered, so it is

Comment: @JustinCave it is RAC cluster.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak my application would receive msg from ems queue, and then call the function to generate id for each msg, in fact there are so much queue so that it would generate so much id at a monent. For example, the above case timestamp is 2019090304401699. I use 'FWK2-2019090304401699-' to search all matched log, but just found that there a 5-8 id at this moment.

Comment: @Needlefile this is worth a try

Comment: @JoopEggen i am not understand yet, although my sequence is NOCACHE, why should `SELECT /*+ NO_RESULT_CACHE */ 'FWK2-'`

Comment: Much hope I did not have, sequence || timestamp erroneously being cached, but it would at least (superfluously?) harden the query.

Comment: Are your RAC node clocks synchronized? I believe it's possible for `current_timestamp` (or `systimestamp`) to return different values on different nodes when not; which means calls actually made at different (real) times could end up with the same timestamp - so looking for a sequence cycle wouldn't necessarily help. They might have to be some way out if you only have 5-8 against that time; but maybe still more likely that sequences being broken?